# SwiftUI Issue displaying specific number of Json Data Items

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am using SwiftUI and pulling JSON from an Online API. I have decoded the item and now struggling trying to display only 6 of the items at random. The 6 items will display once a button has been clicked but I have not created the button yet. Any Ideas on how to display 6 items at random?

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct TestPost: View {
    @ObservedObject var getData = ListData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                // Not Working...
                // Displaying Json Data, I want to display 6 at random when view appears.
                ForEach(getData.jsonData.indices, id: \.self) { item in
                    if item < 6 {
                        ListRow(firstName: item.firstName)
                    }
                }
                
                //Working... Able to Display Names
                List(getData.jsonData) { item in
                    ListRow(firstName: item.firstName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Displaying JSON Items in List]

[image: Fetching JSON]

Comment: Since we are given no _idea_ of what your `ListData()` constructor returns it is incredibly hard to determine what is going wrong. Please post a more simplified example where you provide a String representation of the data you get from your service and try to turn it into JSON and then the VStack. Most likely this exercise will already tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: @Patru If you look on the right side of 1st Image you will see a preview of all the names that are returned. The JSON format it is pulling from looks like "firstName": "Joel". At this point I have figured out how to list the 6 first items from ListData(). My question is how do you randomize the 6 items each time the is refreshed or displayed?

Comment: If you are having a List I would consider writing a function to select 6 at random?

Answer (score 1):

Updated Code!
I figured out how to get the 6 items and will be working on how to do it at random.

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct TestPost: View {
    @ObservedObject var getData = ListData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                // Not Working...
                // Displaying Json Data, I want to display 6 at random when view appears.
                ForEach(getData.jsonData.indices, id: \.self) { item in
                    if item < 6 {
                        ListRow(firstName: self.getData.jsonData[item].firstName) //Updated Code...
                    }
                }
                
                //Working... Able to Display Names
                List(getData.jsonData) { item in
                    ListRow(firstName: item.firstName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```