# Swiftui Creating a load more button for Json data items

Tags: json, foreach, swiftui

I have not gotten to 50 reputation so i could not comment on this question [SwiftUI Issue displaying specific number of Json Data Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992853/swiftui-issue-displaying-specific-number-of-json-data-items) to ask how it was done. The idea is to have the first 10 items in a json array show when the view is loaded and then a load more button to show more items.
This is how my code looks like.

```
Group {

    HStack {
        Text("Recommended Events")
           .font(.title3)
           .foregroundColor(.white)
           .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    
          Spacer()
                                    
           Button(action: {
            
           }) {
             Text("Show all")
               .font(.title3)
               .foregroundColor(Color.white)
               .fontWeight(.bold)
               }
           }
            .padding(15)

    ForEach(recommendeds) { recommended in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: RecommendedEventsDetailView(recommended: recommended)) {
                                    RecommendedEventsView(recommended: recommended)
                                    }
                                }

}
```

Edited

After https://stackoverflow.com/users/14733292/raja-kishan response i tried it and got this error Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report This is the stage of my code now.

```
struct RecommendedModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var number: Int
    
    init(_ number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }
}


struct PlacesView: View { 
private var arrData: [RecommendedModel] = (0...10).map({RecommendedModel($0)})
        
        @State private var isMore: Bool = false
    
    
    //E-MARK: - Body
    var body: some View { 
Group {

    HStack {
        Text("Recommended Events")
           .font(.title3)
           .foregroundColor(.white)
           .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    
          Spacer()
                                    
           Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                                isMore.toggle()
                            }
           }) {
             Text("Show all")
               .font(.title3)
               .foregroundColor(Color.white)
               .fontWeight(.bold)
               }
           }
            .padding(15)

    ForEach( (isMore ? arrData : recommendeds(arrData.prefix(5)))) { recommended in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: RecommendedEventsDetailView(recommended: \(recommended.number)) {
                                    RecommendedEventsView(recommended: \(recommended.number))
                                    }
                                }

}

}
}
```

Below is the Data model i had before that loads the json data saved as RecommendedModel.swift

```
struct Recommended: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let image: String
    let date: String
    let month: String
    let like: String
    let rating: String
    let heading: String
    let place: String
    let article: String
    let more: String
    
}
```

Comment: What's wrong currently?

Comment: I already know it entails using an ObservedObject to control the data from the https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui but in the example it is for a toggle and i could not using a swiftui button

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

You can load the first 10 or 50 by `.prefix()` from the array.

Demo code

```
struct DataModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var number: Int
    
    init(_ number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }
}

struct LoadMoreDemo: View {
    
    private var arrData: [DataModel] = (0...100).map({DataModel($0)})
    
    @State private var isMore: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach( (isMore ? arrData : Array(arrData.prefix(15)))) { item in
                    Text("\(item.number)")
                }
            }
            
            Button("Load More") {
                withAnimation {
                    isMore.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]